# They Pierced My Side After I Had Commended, to Which They Realised All of This Was Intended

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *They put nails in me, although I am not a frame. 
> Above my crown was a mock of my name. 
>  Luke had written what I said to the daughters. 
>  Embark without me — I may walk on the waters. 
>  
>  Often, I would hide as the crowd should not see. 
>  Friends caught the fish before recognising me. 
>  
>  Cries were loud at around the ninth hour. 
>  Hearing them, they offered me a drink too sour. 
>  Robbers were with me; our heads most high. 
>  In accordance with a few, I then rose to the sky. 
>  Some now believe that I might come again. 
>  Treat others the way I had treated you then.*

This riddle *entails* the consequence of faith.

---

**Edit:**

Removed the word "for" in the fourth (and last) line of the first paragraph, namely, 
 `Embark without me, for I may walk on the waters.` 
 and replaced it with a hyphen "—" to better match syllables, turning into what it is currently: 
 `Embark without me — I may walk on the waters.`

Comment: This is another one that seems to me Not Really A Puzzle. To anyone who knows the story in question, it's simply a description in slightly flowery language, no?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yes, I see your point. I am trying to work on my riddles, sir; I am doing different things like making the capital letters spell a certain word, using multiple references from somewhere else, and trying to use puns and/or rhyme. Please trust that my riddles will at some point, get better to a "Real" Puzzle standard. Is there anything you can suggest? :(

Comment: Please don't take my words as meaning that your riddles are no good! Some of them are much trickier than this one, and even the ones that are too easy for my taste are pretty well constructed. The question I think you should be asking is something like this: Is some sort of mental leap required in order to find the answer?

Comment: This is a beautiful poem really well written, but I have to agree with Gareth in saying that it's a tad too obvious to be a puzzle.

Comment: In this case, not much of a leap is called for. On the face of it, this is looking for a person rather than a thing. Quick, think of a person who was nailed to something! Yup, you got it :-). Or: Quick, think of a person who is famous for predicting that they'll "come again"! Well, in this case you _might_ pick General MacArthur or Arnold Schwarzenegger ... but the subject of this riddle is certainly in anyone's top three.

Comment: And the same goes for several of the other clues (and the title): our subject is the single most famous person associated with the thing in question. For something to make an effective _puzzle_, it needs not to be the first thing you think of. But, again, it's nicely constructed, and I do not _at all_ want to discourage you from making puzzles here.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan ok, thank you very much. I will try to make my language more ambiguous, so it is unclear as to what the answer is, and try to make people guess something else at first. And no, you have not discouraged me to make puzzles, so no need to worry. It's just that I love to make riddles, and it's a bit harder because I am restricted with words as I love to make them rhyme (but all the more challenging!), but there are some puzzles and riddles on this site that are brilliant! I will keep working, and will take everyone's advice :)

Comment: FYI, there's no need to annotate your edits unless they are a significant change worth calling out because they may greatly impact solvers' progress or answers. Edit histories are fully visible to anyone who cares to look at what was changed, so there's no need to call out minor edits - it makes the post look cluttered. (Also, the answer should never be included in the question posting, even under spoilers - remember your puzzle may be seen by someone else long after the fact, and they would be disappointed to look in a spoiler tag expecting a hint and instead have the answer revealed.)

Comment: @Rubio $\diamondsuit$ sorry, lasttime I read this comment, I had misread it. The answer *was* in the spoiler tag, but I thought I had already accepted the answer, so it did not matter whether or not I had the answer now. But, being a little bit more considerate, I realise this is not necessarily true. I will take down the answer, even if user **SMR** has kindly put it in a spoiler tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> Jesus ?

They put nails in me, although I am not a frame.

> He was crucified, i.e. nailed on the cross

Above my crown was a mock of my name.

> [INRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus,_King_of_the_Jews)

Luke had written what I said to the daughters.

> [Daughters of Jerusalem, ...](http://biblehub.com/luke/23-28.htm)

Embark without me, for I may walk on the waters.

> [Aqualevitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_walking_on_water)

Friends caught the fish before recognising me.

> [John 21:3-4](https://biblehub.com/john/21-4.htm)

Cries were loud at around the ninth hour.

> [Matthew](https://biblehub.com/matthew/27-46.htm)

Hearing them, they offered me a drink too sour.

> [Just below](https://biblehub.com/matthew/27-48.htm)

Robbers were with me; our heads most high.

> [Robbers](https://biblehub.com/matthew/27-38.htm)

For the three final lines

> it the Ascension, the faith that Jesus would come back and one of the positive value of Christianity

Note that

> the first letter of each line is Tale of Christ

Comment: Would you care to explain every line? :) **Added:** The goal of the riddle is not do that. It is to show the answer and explain why it is that through every line. If it means you having to go through the bible, I will Rot13 some of the phrases to spare you the hassle.

Comment: Being on Puzzling, I thought it was recommended to explain every line to give a "good" and "thorough" answer. If it is not relevant, I apologise.

Comment: Sorry I was convinced I was missing something; now I am just unsure :/ anyway, is this better?

Comment: Well, that's what I thought. Once again, apologies if you had to spend a bit of time on research. I have to wait $17$ hours before I can upvote (because of my daily voting limit), but there is something else I can do...